# Do CTEs generate row duplicates in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been using CTEs (common table expressions) to write small queries that will be used for the 'bigger picture' queries.

For example, I will create a CTE to make a column of counts.

Then basically create a duplicate of that column with another CTE.

Then join them together such that I can create a rolling-sum of the counts for a 30-day window.

Everything seems to be working, I just end up with a table with multiple rows with the same values, therefore total counts (sums) are incorrect.

Is this just a common occurrence when using CTEs or am I doing something incorrectly to create the duplicate rows?

Let's say I have 'table1':

```
row_number | session_date | user_id | item
1           2017-01-01      alex      apple
2           2017-01-02      alex      orange
```

The objective is to have rolling sum of items that the user buys.

```
WITH TEMP
AS (
    SELECT a.row_number
        ,a.session_date
        ,a.user_id
        ,a.item
        ,CASE 
            WHEN a.item = 'apple'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS item_apple
        ,CASE 
            WHEN a.item = 'orange'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS item_orange
    FROM table1 AS a
    )
    ,duplicate
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TEMP
    )
    ,new_table
AS (
    SELECT l.row_number
        ,r.session_date
        ,r.user_id
        ,r.item
        ,sum(r.item_apple) OVER (
            PARTITION BY r.session_date
            ,r.user_id
            ) AS sum_apple_30day
        ,sum(r.item_orange) OVER (
            PARTITION BY r.session_date
            ,r.user_id
            ) AS sum_orange_30day
    FROM TEMP AS l
    LEFT JOIN TEMP AS r ON (l.row_number = r.row_number)
    LEFT JOIN duplicate dp ON l.user_id = dp.user_id
        AND l.session_date <= dp.session_date
        AND l.session_date + interval '30 days' > dp.session_date
    )
SELECT *
FROM new_table
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dade8/2/0

PostgreSQL 9.6

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: "Is this just a common occurrence when using CTEs or am I doing something incorrectly to create the duplicate rows?" - you are doing something incorrectly....

Comment: do you mind pointing me in the right direction? Is there a more simple way to solve this problem?

Comment: Query has been updated to reflect what was commented above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below.

```
WITH temp  AS
(
SELECT
 user_id, item, MIN(session_date) AS FirstDate
FROM table1
GROUP BY user_id, item
),
DateVals AS
(

  SELECT
   t.*,   
 (CAST (DATE_PART('day', t.session_date ::timestamp -  md.FirstDate ::timestamp)  AS INTEGER)) / 30 AS windowValue
  FROM table1  AS t INNER JOIN temp AS md ON 
  t.user_id = md.user_id AND  t.item = md.item
 )
SELECT 
 dv.row_number, dv.user_id, dv.item,dv.session_date,
  ac.AppleCount , oc.OrangeCount
 FROM DateVals AS dv
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (
       SELECT
           row_number,                  

            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id,item,windowValue  ORDER BY session_date) AS AppleCount
       FROM DateVals
      WHERE item = 'apple'
   )AS ac ON dv.row_number = ac.row_number

   LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (
       SELECT
           row_number,       

            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id,item,windowValue  ORDER BY session_date) AS OrangeCount
       FROM DateVals
      WHERE item = 'orange'
   )AS oc ON dv.row_number = oc.row_number
ORDER BY dv.user_id, dv.item,dv.session_date
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. I am new to SQL so this is great help.